# XSLT for each does not display all entries from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML with promotion codes that I want to display somewhere. I want to show all three entries of my XML but when I use a XSLT for each function I get the first entry three times. I want to display all three of them in a good looking row.

The XML I use:

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:s="https://www.zdnet.com/search" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Promotions</title>
        <promotions>
            <promotion>
                <enddate>20-01-2022</enddate>
                <link>https://www.example.com/code/</link>
                <title>Good deal!</title>
                <description>this is a good deal</description>
                <code>Discount10</code>
                <image>https://example.com/favicon.ico</image>
            </promotion>
            <promotion>
                <enddate>19-01-2022</enddate>
                <link>https://www.example.com/code/</link>
                <title>bad deal!</title>
                <description>This is a bad deal</description>
                <code />
                <image>https://example.com/favicon.ico</image>
            </promotion>
            <promotion>
                <enddate>18-01-2022</enddate>
                <link>https://www.example.com/code/</link>
                <title>Super deal!</title>
                <description>This deal is superb.</description>
                <code>discount75</code>
                <image>https://example.com/favicon.ico</image>
            </promotion>
        </promotions>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

The XSLT I use for displaying the entries:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/rss/channel/promotions/promotion"> 
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 60px; padding: 0px;">
                            <img alt="shop logo" style="margin-right: 16px; width: 60px; height: 60px; border-radius: 50%">
                                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/promotions/promotion/image" />
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            </img>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline">
                            <div style="padding-right: 16px; font-size: 16px; color: #0A344F; font-weight: bold;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/promotions/promotion/title" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span style="padding-right: 16px; font-size: 14px;">Your discount:</span>
                            <span
                                class="discount-code" 
                                style="background-color: #0A344F; font-weight: bold; padding: 8px 16px; color: white; text-align: center; border-radius: 8px; font-size: 14px; word-break: keep-all; cursor: text;"
                            >
                                <xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/promotions/promotion/code" />
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 10px;"></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="display: flex;">
                            <a 
                                style="background-color: #FF0054; color: white; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 8px; width: 100%; text-align: center; border: 0px; padding: 8px 16px; text-decoration: none; display: block;"
                            >
                                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/promotions/promotion/link" />
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                Shop nu!
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </html>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a row for each `promotion`, then create only **one** `tr` for each `promotion`. And use a **relative** path from the current `promotion` to get the values for the row's cells. Also create the `html` and `table` wrappers **before** calling `xsl:for-each` to create the table rows.

Here is a simplified example:

**XST 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/rss">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:for-each select="channel/promotions/promotion">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="description" />
                        </td>
                        <!-- more fields -->
                    </tr>               
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>Good deal!</td>
            <td>this is a good deal</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>bad deal!</td>
            <td>This is a bad deal</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Super deal!</td>
            <td>This deal is superb.</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Rendered as:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the `for-each`, instead of the absolute paths you have used, like `<xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/promotions/promotion/image" />`, use relative ones, like `<xsl:value-of select="image"/>`.